# Get value of multiple TextFields in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I have 4 `TextFields` and I want to loop through them to check if they have a value. The `TextFields` are created in a `GetCell` method from my `TableViewController`.

```
public UITextField TextField;

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        if (elements [indexPath.Row].Type == "textField") {

            EditField element = elements [indexPath.Row] as EditField;

            NSString FieldID = new NSString ("EditField");

            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (FieldID);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            var setTextField = cell.ViewWithTag (99) as UITextField;

            if (setTextField == null) {
                TextField = new UITextField ();
                TextField.Placeholder = element.Placeholder;
                TextField.Tag = 99;
                TextField.SecureTextEntry = element.Secure;

                cell.AddSubview (TextField);

                EditFieldProperties ();
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = element.Label;
            cell.DetailTextLabel.Hidden = true;

            return cell;
        } 
    }
```

How can I loop all the `TextFields` to get all the values? I think I need to store them in an `array` or a `dictionary` but I don't know how to.

All I can get is the value of the last `TextField` with this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(TextField.Text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a new `List` of `UITextFields` like this:

```
public List<UITextField> TextFieldList = new List<UITextField>();
```

And looping them like this:

```
foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
    if (item.Text == "") {
        item.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine (item.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest it's to create a list of textfields, so define the list some where in the code and init in the constructor

```
public List<UITextField> YourTextFields = new List<UITextField>();

public YouTableViewSourceConstructor()
{
    foreach(var elementItem in elements.Where(e => e.Type == "textField").ToList())
    {
        YourTextFields.Add(new UITextField(){Tag = 99});
    }
}
```

then in the GetCell method

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //some your code

    if(cell.ViewWithTag (99) != null)
    {
        cell.RemoveSubview(cell.ViewWithTag (99));
    }

    var textField = YourTextFields [elements.Where(e => e.Type == "textField").ToList().IndexOf(elements [indexPath.Row])];
    cell.AddSubview (textField);

    //some your code
}
```

So in the YourTextFields you will have all your 4 textfields and your can easily access to them

Comment: I think this is in the right direction but the number of `UITextFields` is dynamic because they are created from a Json file so the `4` fields is just an example here.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, with a different code but you pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a separate class for cell and name it "CustomCell" and inherit it from `UITableViewCell`.
Make four text fields in its constructor and set the location of those text fields by overriding "LayoutSubview" function of `UITableViewCell` like below:

```
public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

CustomCell
{

//Create text fields here
UITextView TextField1=new UITextView();
this.AddSubView(TextField1);

}

public override void LayoutSubviews ()
{

// set location of text fields in cell as below

 TextField1.Frame=new RectangleF( 32, 8, 60, 15);

}


}//end class
```

I hope this will definitely help you.

Comment: I already have CustomCells but made in my Storyboard with Prototype Cells. In the `GetCell` method I create the `TextFields`, I think I need to put them in a Dictionary or an Array but I don't know how.

Comment: speetje try the above idea,i hace changed the code a bit for clarification,it will help,do things programatically :)